# Pressing 'update' button in my Php edit page while a field is empty removes the id from the URL

Tags: php, html, post, content-management-system

So I have a PHP CRUD system which adds, edits and deletes entries from/to a database. The CMS in question is a drugs table. I can add drugs to this table using the add button and filling in a form, I can also delete the drugs by simply deleting them. But the one of issue is the edit/update part of the system.

The edit feature itself works fine, I'm able to edit an entry and it will post to the database and show up in the table because the user gets redirected back to the table page which shows all the drugs, however, when I remove the text from a field, leaving it empty, and press update, I get an error message which says a text field is empty, however, I also notice the id at the top of the page is no longer there which gives me an Undefined index:error.

I've narrowed the problem down to it being simply because the input type "submit" removes it for some reason.

URL before pressing update with a text field empty:
php_files/DrugEdit.php?Drug_ID=23

URL after pressing update with a text field empty:
eMAR/php_files/DrugEdit.php

**How the program works (with code):**

Php variable created by getting the Drug_ID from the URL (in this case 23)

```
$Drug_ID = $_GET['Drug_ID'];
```

Then gets the field data from the database and assigns them to variables

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM drugs WHERE Drug_ID=$Drug_ID");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $Drug_Name = $res['Drug_Name'];
    $Allergies = $res['Allergies'];
    $Side_effects = $res['Side_effects'];
    $Type_of_Medication = $res['Type_of_Medication'];
    $Dosage = $res['Dosage'];
}
?>
```

The data is then shown in a form where I can edit the data

```
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="DrugEdit.php">
        <table border="0">

            <tr> 
                <td>Drug_Name <?php echo $drug_name_error ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" Name="Drug_Name" value="<?php echo $Drug_Name;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Allergies</td>
                <td><input type="text" Name="Allergies" value="<?php echo $Allergies;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Side_effects</td>
                <td><input type="text" Name="Side_effects" value="<?php echo $Side_effects;?>"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr> 
                <td>Type_of_Medication</td>
                <td><input type="text" Name="Type_of_Medication" value="<?php echo $Type_of_Medication;?>"></td>
            </tr>
                         <tr> 
                <td>Dosage</td>
                <td><input type="text" Name="Dosage" value="<?php echo $Dosage;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" Name="Drug_ID" value=<?php echo $_GET['Drug_ID'];?>></td>
                <td><input type="submit" Name="update" value="Update"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

If the update button gets pressed, it runs the block of code below:

```
$drug_name_error = " ";

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{    
    $Drug_ID = $_POST['Drug_ID'];
    $Drug_Name=$_POST['Drug_Name'];
    $Allergies=$_POST['Allergies'];
    $Side_effects=$_POST['Side_effects'];
    $Type_of_Medication=$_POST['Type_of_Medication']; 
    $Dosage=$_POST['Dosage']; 

    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($Drug_Name) || empty($Allergies) || empty($Side_effects) || empty($Type_of_Medication) || empty($Dosage)) {

        if(empty($Drug_Name)) {
            $drug_name_error = "<font color='red'>Drug_Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($Allergies)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Allergies field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($Side_effects)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Side_effects field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }     

        if(empty($Type_of_Medication)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Type_of_Medication field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }    
        if(empty($Dosage)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Dosage field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }    
    } else {    
        //updating the table
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE drugs SET Drug_Name='$Drug_Name' ,Allergies='$Allergies' ,Side_effects='$Side_effects' ,Type_of_Medication='$Type_of_Medication',Dosage='$Dosage' WHERE Drug_ID=$Drug_ID");

        //redirecting to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
        header("Location: ../drug_manager.php");
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my problem. Hopefully I've provided enough information for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> input type "submit" removes it for some reason

Because you're submitting the form, and the URL for the form submit action is defined in the `<form>` element:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="DrugEdit.php">
```

Note that there's no `Drug_ID` value on that URL.  However, in the form processing code you're not *looking* for it in the URL, you're looking for it in the form post:

```
$Drug_ID = $_POST['Drug_ID'];
```

So I'm not really sure where you're getting that error.  But if somewhere in your form logic you're *also* looking for `$_GET['Drug_ID']`, or simply want it to be on the URL for some downstream need, then you can just add it to that URL:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="DrugEdit.php?Drug_ID=<?php echo $_GET['Drug_ID'];?>">
```

Comment: Ah such a simple answer to such a long winded question. Although I no longer get the error, and the ID shows at the top of the page, is it possible to leave the text fields empty when I remove the text from them? Because when I press update when I have no text in the text fields now, the text fields show the original text in them, and not an empty text field.

Comment: @AF1: If that text is being populated by the server-side code then sure.  Check the page source in the browser to confirm that the `value` attributes are explicitly being set.  If so, simply update the code to not set them when you don't want to.  From the looks of the form code, that may just involve conditionally un-setting those variables before outputting the form.

Comment: how would I go about doing this? In the if(empty statements, is it possible for me to clear the text fields? doing  echo "<textarea name='Drug_Name' rows='1' class='drug_text' placeholder=''> test</textarea>";   puts the textfield at the very top of the page, and doesn't just clear the text field? Unless there's another way to do it? Would you be able to help me with this? Thank you.